# Outlook 2013 displaying "We removed extra line breaks from this message" while is sent in unix using "."

Tags: shell, unix, outlook, ksh, mailx

Just want an explanation about an issue (that is already resolved) about sending an email in unix and outlook is displaying in the email "We removed extra line breaks from this message"

I send an email with file names using a loop from an array and those are enumerated as follow:

```
subject="test"
file_index=0
while [ ${file_index} -lt ${#FILES[@]} ]
   do
      body_message=${body_message}"$(( ${file_index} + 1 )). ${FILES[${file_index}]}\n"
      file_index=$(( ${file_index} + 1 ))
   done
```

EMAIL OUTPUT:

```
1. File1.txt 2.file.txt file3.txt
```

the output is not doing the breakline and is putting it all together and outlook display the message ""We removed extra line breaks from this message"

the issue that cause that message in outlook is the line in `$(( ${file_index} + 1 )).` to be exactly is the "." dot.

I tried the same way but changing it to ".-" and that way is working without any issues, you can see it below.

```
subject="test"
file_index=0
while [ ${file_index} -lt ${#FILES[@]} ]
   do
      body_message=${body_message}"$(( ${file_index} + 1 )).- ${FILES[${file_index}]}\n"
      file_index=$(( ${file_index} + 1 ))
   done
```

EMAIL OUTPUT:

```
1.- File1.txt
2.- File2.txt
3.- File3.txt
```

using just ".-" not affect that, I would like to understand why if I use a single dot it display bad the email in outlook.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Send the message in the HTML format - this way Outlook won't mangle the message body.

As for your question, the exact algorithm Outlook uses to remove line breaks is not documented and most likely is subject to change.